# How can I add CC and BCC fields in Gmail app?

Tags: ios, gmail

I wonder how to add CC and BCC fields in Gmail app. I use iOS 9.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Clicking on `+` didn't reveal anything exciting.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just noticed a very small arrow near top right. Click this to reveal cc and bcc.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, they must have added it somewhere between 2016 and 2017.